# Can a device with a single wireless antenna work as a repeater?

Tags: wireless

Not sure where, but I encountered the claim that a device with a single antenna (e.g. laptop) can be configured as a wireless repeater. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a WIFI type system then yes, well kinda. Using Linux it's possible to split the physical interface into two virtual ones. These virtual interface have to be on the same channel however. With this you can treat them as two distinct interfaces, ie, set up routing, firewalling, whatever...

Have a look at [IW](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw)

For other types of systems you would either use a buffer (which the above example does) or seperate antenna, repeater systems mostly use different bands which require different antennas anyway.

Answer (score 2):

An antenna can simultaneously transmit and receive but Tx and Rx have to be at different frequencies to stand any chance of success. There also has to be "blocking" components preventing the large transmit output getting into the receiver input amplifier because the Tx signal will swamp the receiver and make sensible reception of the tiny "wanted" signal an impossibility.

Comment: Yes, for a continuous transmission scheme such as voice or analog video, that is an issue.  For a packet switched scheme however, it may be possible to time multiplex the use of the antenna.